# Is there any property I can use as hover-within?

Tags: html, css

I have been stuck on this for hours.
I have created a nav bar in CSS3 and one of the items it contains is a drop-down menu.

```
    nav {
      background-color: #343a40;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: Hammersmith One;
    }
    
    nav .logo {
      font-size: calc(1vw + 15px);
      margin: calc(0.2vw + 5px) 0 calc(0.3vw + 5px) 1.5vw;
    }
    
    nav .logo #logo-vector img {
      width: calc(1vw + 15px);
      transform: translate(calc(0.4vw + 8px), calc(0.35vw + 1px));
    }
    
    #parent-ul {
      display: flex;
      width: 50%;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    li {
      list-style: none;
      font-size: calc(1vw + 7px);
      word-spacing: 0;
      transition: color 0.15s ease-in;
    }
    
    .list-item a:hover,
    .list-item a:focus {
      color: #d7bcfd;
    }
    
    #nav-more:hover,
    #nav-more:focus {
      color: #d7bcfd;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    li a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .sub-menu {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #nav-more:hover .sub-menu,
    #nav-more:focus .sub-menu,
    #nav-more:focus-within .sub-menu,
    .sub-menu .child-menu:hover{
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 1px;
      background-color: #343a40;
      padding: 0.8vw;
      transform: translateX(-4vw);
      line-height: 2;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .sub-menu a:hover,
    .sub-menu a:active {
      color: #d7bcfd;
    }
```

***Whenever I hover on 'More' it shows the dropown menu but as soon as I try to hover on any of the options in the dropdown it disappears.***
What I want is just a `:focus` pseudo-class. There is a `:focus-within` so that even if I focus within my 'More' option, the dropdown menu stays, so if I can get a `:hover-within` pseudo-class then it will stay, but unfortunately, there is no pseudo-class like that.
What should I do?

Comment: Can you share your HTML too ?

Comment: There is no property as 'focus-within', instead you can put your dropdown inside your menu item element, such a way that the 'More' will be focused even if you focus on the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Done!

I just had to add `z-index: 1` in my

```
#nav-more:hover .sub-menu,
#nav-more:focus .sub-menu,
#nav-more:focus-within .sub-menu,
.sub-menu .child-menu:hover{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1px;
  background-color: #343a40;
  padding: 0.8vw;
  transform: translateX(-4vw);
  line-height: 2;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Thanks for all the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you check here, the hover will stay on focus even if I hover over the dropdown elements. This way you can achieve what you are looking for

```css
.nav-item:hover {
  color: red;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none
}

.nav-item:hover > .dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item">One</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Two</li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <span>More</span>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="dd-item">More one</li>
        <li class="dd-item">More two</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```